# How to add the title in multiple plots according to the column name of data set in R?

Tags: r, plot, title

```
keep.beta
  beta_0 C1   beta_1 C1     beta_2 C1 beta_0 C2 beta_1 C2    beta_2 C2 beta_0 C3  beta_1 C3    beta_2 C3
1  6.118431  0.14186598 -8.898830e-04  6.022789 0.2284664 -0.008715484  6.362422  0.1623198 -0.007603638
2  6.063539  0.13401758  5.027927e-06  5.986915 0.2469357 -0.009225261  6.150559  0.2002901 -0.007515155
3  6.193407  0.05483201  6.126576e-03  5.841100 0.3347416 -0.016506298  7.146271 -0.3979893  0.041127363
4  6.078092  0.05110730  6.354140e-03  5.562972 0.4690519 -0.027162758  8.179671 -1.0250484  0.089065099
5  6.256228 -0.09785900  1.856215e-02  5.644385 0.4701571 -0.027528102  8.394842 -1.2646359  0.106934875
  beta_0 C4   beta_1 C4    beta_2 C4
1  6.097189  0.16624813 -0.004341827
2  6.164902  0.09360776  0.002282821
3  6.211754  0.03602315  0.007230330
4  6.505551 -0.10780312  0.016602683
5  6.692843 -0.24754950  0.028275593
```

To plot each column separately, I am using the following loop,

```
loop.vector=1:ncol(keep.beta)
  #plot for beta
  for(b in loop.vector) {
    x.beta<-keep.beta[,b]
    plot(x.beta, type = "l", main=paste("beta",b), ylab="") #Change the matin title
    mtext("beta plot",line=-1.5, cex=1.5, outer = TRUE)
    }
```

How can I change the `title`? I am expecting `beta_0 C1` for the first plot, `beta_1 C1` for the second plot and so on. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about `main=colnames(keep.beta)[b]`? See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html

Comment: can I replace the all the betas  title mathematically? for example, first title is `$\beta_0$ c1`, second title is `$\beta_1$ c1`. I want to replace all betas as math notation.